# Download WebView content in WInRT application

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to build a universal rss application for Windows 10 that could be able to download the content of the full article's page for offline consultation.

So after spending a lot of time on stackoverflow I've found some code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AllowAutoRedirect = true };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(ni.Url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

However this solution doesn't work on some web page where the content is dynamically called.

So the alternative that remains seems to be that one: load the web page into the Webview control of WinRT and somehow copy and paste the rendered text.
BUT, the Webview doesn't implement any copy/paste method or similar so there is no way to do it easily.

And finally I found this post on stackoverflow ([Copying the content from a WebView under WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940629/copying-the-content-from-a-webview-under-winrt)) that seems to be dealing with the same exact problematic as mine with the following solution;

Use the InvokeScript method from the webview to copy and paste the content through a javascript function.

It says: "First, this javascript function must exist in the HTML loaded in the webview."

```
function select_body() {
var range = document.body.createTextRange(); 
range.select();
}
```

and then "use the following code:"

```
// call the select_body function to select the body of our document
MyWebView.InvokeScript("select_body", null);

// capture a DataPackage object
DataPackage p = await MyWebView.CaptureSelectedContentToDataPackageAsync();

// extract the RTF content from the DataPackage
string RTF = await p.GetView().GetRtfAsync();

// SetText of the RichEditBox to our RTF string
MyRichEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, RTF);
```

But what it doesn't say is **how to inject the javascript function if it doesn't exist in the page I'm loading** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a WebView like this:

```
<WebView Source="http://kiewic.com" LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"></WebView>
```

Use `InvokeScriptAsync` in combination with `eval()` to get the document content:

```
private async void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebView webView = sender as WebView;
    string html = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync(
        "eval",
        new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });

    // TODO: Do something with the html ...
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(html);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for ! However: on some websites it will not bring me the rendering of the webpage but only some html/javascript code that doesn't contain the text I want to display. I'm trying to build a rss news reader that can save the full article for offline viewing. Therefore the only option that worked was to use eval on  "document.documentElement.outerText" rather than "document.documentElement.outerHTML". Unfortunately this brings me a lot of useless text from menu, comments etc...